# Merge two lists (non equal elements) in a csv using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two lists whose no. of elements are not equal. I want to put these two lists in a csv whose heading is 'video' and 'image'. But as the elements of these 2 lists are not the same I got an error.

```
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

import pandas as pd
VID = ['00001', '05445', '987457', '15455'] 
IMG = ['00001', '05445', '987457'] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"video": VID, "image": IMG})
df.to_csv("./file.csv", sep=',',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to `Series` first:

```
import pandas as pd
VID = ['00001', '05445', '987457', '15455'] 
IMG = ['00001', '05445', '987457'] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"video": pd.Series(VID), "image": pd.Series(IMG)})
df.to_csv("./file.csv", sep=',',index=False)
```

More generic approach if many items:

```
names = ['video', 'image']
vals = [VID, IMG]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(names, map(pd.Series, vals))))
df.to_csv("./file.csv", sep=',',index=False)
```

Comment: If '15455' is in the middle of the list, then in image column the column is shifted up.I mean video image 0 00001 00001 1 05445 05445 2 15455 987457 3 987457

Comment: So those are ids, not values and you want to align them?

Comment: Yes. I need them in the same alignment

Comment: can you please update your question with the example and provide the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion 1:

Using None to create an "empty value"/null value

```
import pandas as pd
VID = ['00001', '05445', '987457', '15455'] 
IMG = ['00001', '05445', '987457', None] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"video": VID, "image": IMG})
```

Suggestion 2:

```
import pandas as pd
VID = ['00001', '05445', '987457', '15455'] 
IMG = ['00001', '05445', '987457', '0'] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"video": VID, "image": IMG})
```

Comment: But the list in not known to me. It's a code generated list (length approx 32340)

Answer (score 0):

Because these are ids and looks sorted , we can create temp lists. However we need  O(m+n) extra space and o(m) or o(n) extra time to make solution work

```
temp_vid = [] 
temp_img = []

i,j = 0,0


while i<len(VID) and j<len(IMG):
    #In case when number in both of list , add it to temp lists and move forward
    if VID[i] == IMG[j]:
        temp_vid+=[VID[i]]
        temp_img+=[IMG[j]]
        i+=1
        j+=1
    #In case when number is in any of the list, keep that number in corresponding temp list and None to another list
    elif VID[i]<IMG[j]:
        temp_vid+=[VID[i]]
        temp_img.append(None)
        i+=1
    #In case when number is in any of the list, keep that number in corresponding temp list and None to another list
    else:
        temp_vid.append(None)
        temp_img+=[IMG[j]]
        j+=1

# If Any of list ends, add None to corresponding temp list and add numbers of the other list to corresponding other temp list.  
    while j<len(IMG):
        temp_img.append(None)
        j+=1
         if j== len(IMG):
    while i<len(VID):
        temp_vid.append(None)
        i+=1


df = pd.DataFrame({"video": pd.Series(temp_vid), "image": pd.Series(temp_img)})
```

df

```
    video   image
0   00001   00001
1   05445   05445
2   15455   None
3   987457  987457
```

Comment: If '15455' is in the middle of the list, then in image column the column is shifted up.I mean            video   image
0   00001    00001
1   05445    05445
2   15455    987457
3   987457

Comment: It's working without error. But column is shifted up